# map function to get radius data from csv for d3 force layout

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to pull in csv data into d3.map in order to create a radius similar to what Mike Bostock did [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298). But instead of using random numbers, pull in the data. The rest of the code seems to work fine when I throw a random number in there. Any help would be appreciated as I am still a noob to d3.

```
    d3.csv("fuel.csv", function(csv) {

for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
                parseFloat(csv[i].comb),
}

var nodesFuel = d3.range(csv.length)
                  .map(csv, function(d) { 
                      return {radius: d.comb};
                    });

    ...
```

Comment: First:  this has nothing to do with [d3.map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_map); it is using the [map function of Javascript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the original code:

```
var nodes = d3.range(200).map(function() { 
                                  return {radius: Math.random() * 12 + 4}; 
                             });
```

It starts with `d3.range(200)`.  That function creates an array of integers from 0 to 199.  Then that array's `.map( callbackFunction )` method is called.  The map function creates a new array of the same length as the array that calls it, but each element of the new array is the value returned from the callback function.  The callback function is given the value from the array and its index as parameters, but those aren't used here.  Instead, the integers are ignored and a new object is returned, containing a single property, radius, set to a random number between 4 and 16.

Another way to do the same thing (using a syntax that might be more familiar if you have experience with other programming languages) would be:

```
var nodes = new Array(200);
for(var i=0; i<200; i++) {
    nodes[i] = {radius: (Math.random() * 12 + 4)};
}
```

Either way, the end result is just a 200-element array of objects with random radius values.

This is all unrelated to the [`d3.map` object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-maps), which is a formal implementation of a hashmap data structure, for use if there is a possibility that your data keys will conflict with internal Javascript Object properties and function names.

Now, as to what you are trying to do.  The `d3.csv` function reads your file and creates an array of named objects.  That array is passed as the parameter to your callback function.  If you want to create a new array of objects, each one of which is based on a separate data row from your csv file, then you could call the array mapping function on your `csv` array directly:

```
d3.csv("fuel.csv", function(csv) {

/* This doesn't do anything.  
// You're parsing the strings but not saving the result!
for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
                parseFloat(csv[i].comb),
}
*/

var nodesFuel = csv.map(function(d) { 
                      return {radius: parseFloat(d.comb) };
                    });

/* or if you want to save the parsed value in the original array:
var nodesFuel = csv.map(function(d) { 
                      d.comb = parseFloat(d.comb);
                      return {radius: d.comb };
                    });
*/
```

The array `nodesFuel` is now an array the same length as `csv`, with each entry an object containing the property `radius`, where the radius value is the parsed value of the `comb` property from the corresponding entry in the `csv` array.

Comment: Makes sense. I hadn't thought of it this way before, but it should be possible to just pass in each element of `nodesFuel` into something like: `d3.selectAll("circle").enter().append("circle").attr(nodesFuel)`, if we called the `radius` property `r` instead, and set up the `cx` and `cy` properties inside the objects beforehand.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, @Yawar: nodesFuel is the data array that you use in the data join like `d3.selectAll("circle").data(nodesFuel).enter().append("circle").attr("r", function(d){return d.radius;});`  The example uses a force layout to set the cx and cy properties.

Comment: Not to worry. My example code is a rough expression of the idea, but the concept is that we can take the input data, re-shape it into a list of objects with keys of SVG attribute names and values of SVG attribute values, and pass them directly in to the `attr` function when we create/update SVG elements.

Comment: Not quite -- not with the current version of d3, anyway.  You can set a single attribute based on data with a function **or** you can set multiple attributes, the same for all elements, with an object containing key-value pairs, but you can't use a function that returns an object to set multiple attributes based on the data all at once.  However, I agree that it would be convenient if you could do that -- I've been meaning to look at the source code to see how complicated it would be to implement!

Comment: I think we can manage it introducing a little bit of inelegance. Say you have an array `attrs` of attribute objects. You can 'pass it in' when creating multiple SVG objects, like so: `d3.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle").each((d, i) => d3.select(this).attr(attrs[i]));`. Then again it may not be worth the effort.